# How to merge data from one table to another

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How do I merge data from one table to another table using merge statement.

```
MERGE INTO TESTDTA.F4311 B
USING (SELECT PDDOCO,PDDCTO,PDKCOO,PDSFXO,PDLNID,PDAMC3 FROM F4311_0226A) S
ON (B.PDDOCO=S.PDDOCO,b.pddcto=s.pddcto,b.pdkcoo=s.pdkcoo,b.pdsfxo=s.pdsfxo,b.pdlnid=s.pdlnid)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
update set b.pdamc3=s.pdamc3
```

But this statement is giving error as below

SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:
*Action:

Comment: Why not use " join "

Comment: The error clause indicates **quite clearly** you are using Oracle, not SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

The `on` clause should use `and`, not `,`:

```
ON (B.PDDOCO = S.PDDOCO and b.pddcto = s.pddcto and b.pdkcoo = s.pdkcoo b.pdsfxo = s.pdsfxo and b.pdlnid = s.pdlnid)
```